# Regex to get a blended link from a wikimarkup page in Java

Tags: java, regex, wiki-markup

I have to check for the following kind of string:

`has [[public transport]]ation in city? some[[times]]`

and return only the relevant parts - i.e.

`[[public transport]]ation`
`some[[times]]`

I am using this regex: `\\w*?\\[\\[(.*?)\\]\\]\\w*?`

It does not seem to work with the example given above and extended examples when the search text contains new lines and special characters too. Can you indicate how i should write the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `.` won't match newlines:

You need to toggle single line mode

```
(?s)\\S*\\[\\[.*?\\]\\]\\S*
 ^
```

With single line mode, `.` would also match newlines

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex with `DOTALL` switch `(?s)`:

```
(?s)\\S*\\[\\[.*?\\]\\]\\S*

System.out.println("has [[public transport]]ation in city? some[[times]]".replaceAll(
    "(?s)\\S*\\[\\[.*?\\]\\]\\S*", "<$0>"));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
has <[[public transport]]ation> in city? <some[[times]]>
```

Comment: What does `"<$0>"` do? Empty space?

Comment: `$0` represents matched string and I used `"<$0>"` to show you working examples of this match.